How to create custom query in Elementor loop grid/carousel placed in a Single Post Template, which will fetch another post type of the same taxonomy?
I have an Elementor Single Post Template for video tutorials. This tutorial has been tagged with a custom taxonomy called 'Project Focus' (example: Branding).
At the bottom of the Single Post Template I have an Elementor loop carousel.  I would like this carousel to Query the post type of "Portfolio", by the Project Focus that the current post is tagged with.  So, if this particular video tutorial is tagged with 'Branding', I would like it to display a carousel filled with 'Branding' Portfolio items.
Essentially, I'm looking to fetch Portfolio posts that are related to the current Video post, by Project Focus taxonomy.
I started with the basic query example from Elementor's documentation.  I have that working in basic form, so adding the custom query into Code Snippets and then the query ID into the Loop Carousel is working, if just to query another post type/s.
What isn't working is the query for taking the current video post's 'project focus' term (such as Branding) and then modifying the query for portfolio items of that identified term.
I've gone back and forth with Chat GPT to iron it out around some errors that caused whitescreen or template destruction.
This is the latest I have:
function custom_case_study_query( $query ) {
    // Ensure we're only modifying the main query.
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the current video-tutorial post's project-element term.
    $location_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'project_focus' );

    if ( ! empty( $location_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $location_terms ) ) {
        // Extract the first term's slug (e.g., 'branding').
        $location_slug = $location_terms[0]->slug;

        // Log the term we're using for filtering.
        error_log( 'Filtering posts by project-element term: ' . $location_slug );

        // Modify the query to only show portfolio-item posts tagged with the same project-element.
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'portfolio' );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project_focus',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $location_slug,
            ),
        ));

        // Exclude the current video-tutorial post (to prevent recursion or conflicts).
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( get_the_ID() ) );

        // Safety: Ensure we have a reasonable number of posts.
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );  // Retrieve all matching posts.
        $query->set( 'no_found_rows', true ); // Skip pagination for performance.

        // Log the final query parameters for debugging.
        error_log( print_r( $query, true ) );

    } else {
        error_log( "No terms found or there was an error retrieving project-element terms." );
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/newcasequery', 'custom_case_study_query' );


newcasequery is the ID I add into Elementor.
This all sits in Code Snippets.

Have you verified that get_the_ID actually returned the correct post ID you were expecting there? (Since that function is meant to work in the loop, I am not sure if it'll work correctly in this filter callback context.)

As C3roe stated, you may want to test if you are getting the data you are expecting. If not, you can probably use get_queried_object_id() which will get the ID for the current post/taxonomy/whatever for whatever the main query object is.

Hi both of you...I apologise for time away...I got dragged elsewhere and this couldn't get time.
So, yes, in short.  The ID is coming back and printing out the required slug. This part seemed successful.
As new as I am to queries, from all I've been learning, this looks like a solid query.  It works if removing the location_slug journey.
